# Get the id of the last inserted row ORACLE/PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How to get the last id using php

similar `mysqli_insert_id($conexao)`

Answer (score 0):

Many Oracle programs use [database objects called `SEQUENCE`s](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) to generate unique IDs.  If you know which sequence is used for the id in the table you just `INSERT`ed into, simply say

```
SELECT sequencename.CURRVAL FROM DUAL;
```

immediately after the insert, in the same database connection, and you'll get the id number.

`SELECT MAX(id)` and similar constructs work fine as long as you only, ever, have one connection to the database: meaning they don't work. Basically they're not thread-safe. They're also more expensive than `CURRVAL`.

Comment: While this may seem trivial to some, this mechanism only makes sense provided you have actually used the sequence in the values inserted... Example: `... VALUES(SEQ_ID_SOMENAME.nextval, ...)`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your ids are auto-incremented in ascending order you could query for the highest id...

```
SELECT id from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

that should give you the highest id and if your ids are auto-incremented this should be the last entry...

Comment: This is subject to race conditions, and is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: I was unaware of any race conditions or unreliability on this query...  If this is in fact true then one could use SELECT MAX(id) from table...

Comment: What if you have several database client programs inserting rows into the table? That's the race. `MAX()` has the same problem.